# "Cohomology Operations" - Steenrod-Epstein: frame fields on $S^{n-1}$ as sections of a fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

In the book "Cohomology Operations" by Steenrod and Epstein, at page 56, the author says that the existence of a field of $k$-frames (i.e. a function that maps a point of the sphere to a $k$-frame tangent to the point) is equivalent to the existence of a section to the fibre bundle $$V_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^n)\longrightarrow V_1(\mathbb{R}^n)=S^{n-1}$$ I do not have that much familiarity with fibre bundles, and I would like to know how they are equivalent.

Thanks to everybody who will answer.

PS: $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Stiefel manifold of $k$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A $k$-frame is a set of $k$ orthonormal vectors.

Comment: Do you already know the special case of the tangent bundle of a manifold $M$, and the fact that a vector field on $M$ is the same thing as a section of the tangent bundle? If not, then the only way to answer your question would be to give you a course on basic differential topology followed by a more advanced course on fiber bundles. But even if you do already know that case, the only answer might still be to give you an advanced course on fiber bundles such as is contained in the book "Fiber bundles" by [Husemoller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale_Husemoller).

Comment: Thanks Lee, I did not know this, I guess I'll have to check Husemoller's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $S^{n-1}$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then, we can identify the tangent space $T_x S^{n-1}$ at $x \in S^{n-1}$ with the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is perpendicular to $x$ regarded as a vector, and furthermore this identification is continuous in $x$.

Now, given a field of $k$-frames $\{\eta_1(x), \ldots, \eta_k(x)\}$, the map $\sigma: x \mapsto (x, \eta_1(x), \ldots, \eta_k(x))$ is a section of $V_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to S^{n-1}$.  Conversely, given a section $\sigma: S^{n-1} \to V_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we can write $\sigma(x) = (x, \eta_1(x), \ldots, \eta_k(x))$, and $\{\eta_1(x), \ldots, \eta_k(x)\}$ is a $k$-frame field on $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I really know nothing about this 